# Unity3D Firebase: InvalidOperationException: FirebaseApp was not initialized with a bucket name

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

I am using the latest version of FirebaseSDK (currently 4.2.1) in my Unity game. I have everything setup as mentioned in the docs. Realtime database and authentication are working fine but I am getting the following error when running in Editor:

> InvalidOperationException: FirebaseApp was not initialized with a bucket name.

when I does the following:

```
StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
```

But if I make the reference using bucket name its fine, for example:

```
StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance.GetReferenceFromUrl("gs://bucketname");
```

does not produce an error.

Anybody having any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you run it on an actual device?

Comment: Yes, its fine on an actual device.  But it should work on Unity Editor as well because I can’t test on an actual device every time I make a change. Device building is very slow.

Comment: @DougStevenson , I made an edit in the original question that if I make the reference using bucket name, it works fine on Unity Editor.

Comment: Right, I'm not suggesting that it's working as intended, but this is important information for the SDK team to know.

Answer (score 0):

When calling App.Create, you can pass in options via the app options struct.  I believe this gets filled automatically, if you are running on device (and it can access the google-services plist/xml) but in the editor, you need to specify it.  If you call FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance.RootReference without doing so, then it won't actually know what the root reference for your project is.  (Getting references directly from gs:// links works, since those are absolute.)

Try setting the bucket via AppOptions when you call App.Create().